# Raw Input keyboard with RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS displays a classic Alt+Tab menu

Tags: winapi, raw-input

I'm trying to disable windows keys for a window that uses RawInput to process keyboard events. The usual way to do this is to install a low-level keyboard hook and filter out windows key events there. In order for it to work with RawInput, I have to initialize the keyboard device with RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS. However, when I do that, if I then Alt+Tab from the app, for some reason Windows 10 displays the classic Alt+Tab thing:

[image: alt-tab menu]

I'm not filtering out Alt or Tab events in the low-level keyboard hook, and this also happens if I don't install a low-level keyboard hook at all, just initializing the keyboard device with RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS does it. I tried returning 0 for WM_INPUT messages, and I tried calling the default window proc, nothing seems to be helping... Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: I think the fancy Alt+Tab comes from the shell, the classic Alt+Tab is deeper down in the window manager.

Answer (score 1):

Add a low level hook ([WH_KEYBOARD_LL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_keyboard_ll)) can prevent Alt key message to pass to other windows. Refer to "[LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)".

WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook can be set only with [global scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#remarks).

```
// Register hook
hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("sysmsg.dll"));
hkprcSysMsg = (SYSMESSAGEPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "SysMessageProc");

HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)hkprcSysMsg, hinstDLL, 0);
```

Hook callback function in DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT __cdecl SysMessageProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (nCode < 0)  // do not process message 
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode,
            wParam, lParam);

    if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        if(((tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode == VK_LMENU || ((tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->vkCode == VK_RMENU)
        return 1;
    }


    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

More reference: "[Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-hooks)" "[Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/keyboard-input)" "[WM_SYSKEYDOWN message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-syskeydown)" "[KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct)" "[Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)"

> **Note**
>
> Hooks tend to slow down the system because they increase the amount of
>   processing the system must perform for each message. You should
>   install a hook only when necessary, and remove it as soon as possible.
>
> You should use global hooks only for debugging purposes; otherwise,
>   you should avoid them. Global hooks hurt system performance and cause
>   conflicts with other applications that implement the same type of
>   global hook.

Comment: According to the documentation, it's not necessary to put low-level hooks into a DLL, because they get invoked by context-switching to the thread that installed the hook, not by injecting the hook into each process. You say that adding low level hooks may prevent other processes from processing Alt key events. Why is that?

Comment: @Kalinovcic [All global hook functions must be in libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#remarks). To receive WM_SYSKEYDOWN message (Alt + ) you need install WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook and it is a global hook that is a [shared resource, and installing one affects all applications in the same desktop as the calling thread.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa#remarks)

Comment: @Kalinovcic Just because WH_KEYBOARD_LL is a global hook so that can affect all application so that can "disable" the ALT + Tab switch window action. If you use WH_KEYBOARD hook you can only receive common WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN message.

Comment: @rita-han-msft But why would it "disable" ALT+Tab if I'm not filtering neither ALT nor Tab? I'm literally just adding a low-level hook that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Note that I'm not trying to filter out ALT key presses, I'm trying to filter out winkey key presses.

Comment: As for placing hook functions in libraries, WH_MOUSE_LL and WH_KEYBOARD_LL are exceptions to the rule. They don't have to be in libraries; they get called in the context of the thread who created the hook, by processing the message queue. That's not the issue, my hook functions get called just fine. My issue is, how do I use low-level keyboard hooks and a RawInput keyboard device at the same time? It seems to either not work, or break the alt-tab thing in some way.

Comment: @Kalinovcic If you "**trying to filter out winkey key presses**" you can refer to "[Using a low-level keyboard hook to disable the Windows key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dxtecharts/disabling-shortcut-keys-in-games#disable-the-windows-key-with-a-keyboard-hook)". Why do you "use low-level keyboard hooks and a RawInput keyboard device at the same time"?

Comment: @rita-han-msft Because RawInput is the only API that properly reports key presses for certain keys, such as the Pause/Break key, Numlock key, Alt Gr on german (and some other) keyboards (it's reported as 2 key presses, ctrl+alt, instead of 1 key press), etc... I'm writing a general-purpose platform-layer library, and I need the ability to properly detect any kind of key press. The KEYDOWN/KEYUP messages are broken for these keys (any others). So, that's why I'm using RawInput. As for your reference for disabling the Windows key, that's what I'm using, but it interferes with RawInput somehow.

Comment: When I use RawInput and low-level keyboard hooks at the same time (and again, I have to use both, because RawInput is the only API that reports everything I need, and low-level keyboard hooks are the only API that can filter out keys), my hook doesn't get called when my window is in focus; it only gets called when some other windows are in focus. And sometimes it doesn't do that, but instead breaks the alt+tab menu. I'm asking if there's some recommended way to use RawInput and low-level hooks together. I know this is somewhat rare. but it's really the only option for me.